# kernel: mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!

Tags: ubuntu, syslog

Every minute these three lines are added to /var/log/syslog:

```
Dec  6 06:04:01 machine1234 kernel: last message repeated 3 times
Dec  6 06:04:01 machine1234 CRON[28959]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 58 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
Dec  6 06:04:01 machine1234 kernel: mdadm: sending ioctl 1261 to a partition!
```

What's going on?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 server edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in linux kernel, but it doesn't seem to be a real problem. Did you make an update of your kernel and or mdadm?

Take a look at the following two links.

- [debian bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=656899)
- [fix on LKML](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/6/15/150)